# Trying to auto run an application on boot

Tags: raspbian, boot

I wanted to run a self made application based on C++ and opencv when I power on my Pi. My application is controlling the GPIO ports as well thus needs to be run as root. Followed a few articles in parts because all the methods of a perticular article were not working. 
1) To auto log in and auto start Pi I have followed this article http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html

2) I copied my application into the ./bin folder

3) To autostart the LXDE terminal and to auto run my application i used the following link http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-autostart-apps-in-rasbian-lxde-desktop/
After doing all this I rebooted my pi but got stuck at boot with the following error

[image]

First I get a blank screen and for a second my Pi-Cam's Led glows then nothing at all then I'll need Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get the above screen. I cannot log into my pi. I tried Ctrl+C, Exit etc but nothing works.

Comment: 3rd link that you provided should work. ie, Add the program in LXDE-pi/autostart file. Here is an example : "@sudo /path/to/application" Please also have a look at paths in your application. They should be absolute paths and not relative.

Comment: Yea that worked  for a couple of times on power on but once i rebooted my pi it didnt

Comment: How did you check it if it worked without rebooting ?

Comment: Also, it seems like you're running an old raspbian. I'm not sure if LXDE-pi existed back then.

Comment: Actually the problem right now is I'm unable to even log into my pi. I'm getting the above output and nothings working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message `FATAL: Module g2d_23 not found.` is not a problem based on [this Raspberry Pi forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=67334#p495233).

I looked at the [Auto Login and Auto Start in Raspberry Pi instructions](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html) you linked to and think you should undo the steps in the `Auto Login` section that have you modify `/etc/inittab`.  Once you do this I think you'll be able to login again.

The steps under `Auto Start the Desktop (LXDE)` should get the RPi to boot to a graphical interface.

From there, I have used [these instructions](https://gocardless.com/blog/raspberry-pi-metric-dashboards/) to get a program running automatically on boot.  I believe the pertinent steps for this are `4. Start Browser on Boot`.

First install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils unclutter
```

Then edit the following file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

To disable the screensaver add the comment mark at the beginning of this line:

```
# @xscreensaver -no-splash
```

These lines will disable power saving interface features:

```
# Turn off screensaver
@xset s off

# Turn off power saving
@xset -dpms

# Disable screen blanking
@xset s noblank

# Hide the mouse cursor
@unclutter
```

And finally, add the line to start your program; something like:

```
@/home/pi/bin/your_program
```